# XPath to return the next column following the td containing a specific text string?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML (a small part of a larger HTML document):

```
<tr class="even">
  <td width="35%"><strong>Restrictions or particulars</strong></td>
  <td>
    MAINTENANCE OF REFRIGERATION/AIR CONDITIONING UP TO 1000v - REFRIGERATION/AIRCON EQPT<br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

What would be the XPath expression that identifies the string `Restrictions or particulars`, and then returns the text in the immediately following `td` (`MAINTENANCE OF REFRIGERATION/AIR CONDITIONING UP TO 1000v - REFRIGERATION/AIRCON EQPT`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways you could do this.  I would select the surrounding `tr` node that has the associated `td` with that name, then take the second `td`.

```
//tr[td[1]='Restrictions or particulars']/td[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//tr[contains(td, 'Restrictions or particulars')]/td[2]/text()
```